# AHK Window activation not working when launching program

Tags: autohotkey

I'm currently the following code to launch the Program SpeedCrunch when pressing Win+C

```
#c::
IfWinExist, SpeedCrunch
{
    WinActivate
}
IfWinNotExist, SpeedCrunch
{
    Run, speedcrunch.exe, C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedCrunch, UseErrorLevel
    WinActivate
}
return
```

Activating the window when the program is running works perfectly. When the program is not running, however, the program is launched minimized, and not activated, meaning that it's necessary to press Win+C two times to launch and bring into focus Speedcrunch, even though I have "WinActivate" in the launch command. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Should work. Try it in a stand-alone script and run the script as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test conditions are not precise enough.

I suggest the following formulation:

```
#c::
IfWinExist, ahk_exe SpeedCrunch.exe
{
    WinActivate
}
IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe SpeedCrunch.exe
{
    Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedCrunch, , UseErrorLevel, process_id
    WinWait, ahk_pid %process_id%
    WinActivate, ahk_pid %process_id%
}
```